# Hibernate two versions of the same object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity that has been loaded from the database in a previous request, that is now modified. It is still detached in the persistence context.

When I'm submitting and entering my save() method, first entityManager.load() gets called to get the previous state of the object, make some comparisons, computations etc. (Im now working with entity and entityBefore)

Saving entity now results in an error. I'm trying to save a different object with the same id.
The solution at the moment is to just detach entityBefore and then use saveOrUpdate. Seemed to work like a charm.

However it only leads to another problem. The entity contains a list of other objects (1-n). Removing one of those from the list returns an error, they've previously been detached aswell.

At the moment I'm not sure what's the best approach to solve this whole thing. How can I manage 2 different versions of the same object, without storing both in the database?  Is there a way I can get the old State from the database without modifying the context? Do I need to refresh every object in the list one by one?...

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Why just simple not to merge new entity back to context when you done with all your checkings? Thus it became managed from detached and you ok with saving it.

Comment: That's what we are doing at the moment. As long as you only add or change things it works just fine. However when you start to remove things from the list, an error occurs. You cant remove detached entities. It's the cascading that makes this fail.